# looping through result rows and storing column data into stored procedure variables mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I m trying to learn stored procedure in mysql. I know the below example does not need SP, but this is ONLY for my learning purpose - just to understand how to loop through rows, and pick specific column data inside the row.

Assume that a SELECT on the table returns 5 records from my table with following structure -

table name: t1
columns: c1,c2,c3

i would like to loop through each of the 5 rows, and for each row, i would like to store the column cell data into SP variables varc1,varc2,varc3, so that varc1 = c1, varc2 = c2, varc3 = c3. i would be using these varc1,varc2,varc3 for further computation while within the loop.

i am assuming that a stored procedure is required, but i am not getting the approach in doing the row iteration and then picking data from each column in the row under consideration in the loop.

quite new to mysql/ stored procedure.
thank you!

Answer (score 6):

What your asking for, as you seem to  know, is a particularly inefficient solution to most problems. However, since you specifically asked for it, and since (very occasionally) it's the only way to solve a problem (or the only way you personally have time to figure out how to solve it). Here's how you might do what you ask:

Create your t1 table eg:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT);
```

Carry out your SELECT that you describe eg:

```
INSERT INTO  t1 SELECT NULL,c1,c2,c3 FROM the_table;
```

Now here's your Row-By-Agonising-Row "ReeBAR" low efficiency stored procedure:

Prepare space for your procedure and set the delimiter:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ReeBAR;
DELIMITER ;;
```

Write your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReeBAR()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE varc1 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE varc2 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE varc3 INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM t1;
set i=1;
WHILE i<=n DO 
  SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE id=i INTO varc1; 
  SELECT c2 FROM t1 WHERE id=i INTO varc2;
  SELECT c3 FROM t1 WHERE id=i INTO varc3;
  --queries which couldnt be made into set based queries go here---
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
```

Alternatively if your id column in not sequential you can use the follwoing cursor form.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReeBAR()
BEGIN
  DECLARE cursor_ID INT;
  DECLARE cursor_VAL VARCHAR;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM t1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  DECLARE varc1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc3 INT DEFAULT 0;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO varc1, varc2, varc3;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    --queries which couldnt be made into set based queries go here---
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
```

Don't forget to "end" the procedure you use and reset the delimiter

```
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally to run your ReBAR procedure

```
CALL ReeBAR();
```

(code untested)

Comment: This won't work if there is a discontinuity in the ids (when performing a DELETE for example).

Comment: @singe3 Why would there be a discontinuity in the id column? Its generated using autoincrement in this case. Never the less for users who want to apply the concept to tables that already exist and may have discontinuous id columns I've edited the answer to allow for them too.

Comment: Thanks for the update ! Actually a discontinuity can happen if the application using the database needs to delete some old entries for some reason.

Comment: You can actually loop using while and get any discontinuis id by playing with the limit like so : SELECT c1 FROM t1 LIMIT i,1 INTO varc1;
Hopes this help

Answer (score 2):

Use CURSORS and a loop to iterate over it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html. Hope this helps!

Comment: MySQL documentation is so bad that links to it are rarely helpful.