# SQL: percolate running total up a tree stored in parent id form in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, iteration, tree-traversal, nested-sets

I have a (simple but large) binary tree stored in an sql table. Each row has an sequentially numbered id (starting at 1), and a parent_id (the root has parent_id 0). There are no loops; moreover, the rows are stored in a nested-set manner such that I can be certain that if I iterate through the rows from 1..n I will always visit child nodes before their parents (i.e. post-order traversal). Nodes also have a few columns (say a,b,c) which are intended to store a running total of the nodes underneath them. The terminal nodes (tips) have numbers assigned in these columns. For example, perhaps one tip (id=1111111) has a=3, b=1, c=5, while its sister node (id=1111112) could have a=0,b=1,c=5. Their immediate parent (id=1111113) should therefore be assigned a=3,b=2,c=10.

My question is how to implement this algorithm to percolate these running totals up the tree to the final node (the root)? I could simply iterate through the nodes using a loop construct (e.g. as in [looping through result rows and storing column data into stored procedure variables mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877244/looping-through-result-rows-and-storing-column-data-into-stored-procedure-variab)), although some pointers for how to do this would be useful (I'm an SQL novice). But I understand that iteration / cursors are generally frowned upon in SQL. Is there another way?

This strikes me as an inherently iterative problem, though, so I would presumably need to ensure that a set-based solution carries out the additions in the correct order, which rather negates the point of avoiding iteration.

I'm doing this in mysql, if that helps.

[Update: added example as per comment]

Starting with a tree like (((1,2)3,(4,5)6)7,8)9

```
id  parent a   b   c
1   3      1   2   3
2   3      4   5   6
3   7  
4   6      7   8   9
5   6      10  11  12
6   7
7   9
8   9      13  14  15
9   0
total:     35  40  45
```

I need to fill it out in the places marked by * as

```
id  parent a   b   c
1   3      1   2   3
2   3      4   5   6
3   7      *5  *7  *9
4   6      7   8   9
5   6      10  11  12
6   7      *17 *19 *21
7   9      *22 *26 *30
8   9      13  14  15
9   0      *35 *40 *45
```

(note that we can check that the root node id=9 now contains the totals from the initial table)

Comment: Although the the answer "MySQL does not support hierarchical queries or recursion in a single query", you should really include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a more comprehensive example. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you lookedat  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ to see if it's helpful?

Comment: @Barmar thanks. The section "AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS IN A NESTED SET" looks helpful, but I have a sinking feeling that doing it this way will be much less efficient then iteration, since the calculations are done independently on each node, while the iterative method percolates sums up the tree. But perhaps the optimiser is super-clever. This tree has 2M nodes, by the way.

Comment: The technique there uses a join, so it may create a very large intermediate table. You'll have to test it to see if performance is acceptable.